# Android studio showing strange behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, compiler-errors

I was doing some sample project but my system went off due to unexpected power cut off. After some time I switched on the system and reopened my existing application but my project is not loading properly.One of my activity in which I was working before power cut off is complete empty and other activities are also showing lots of errors as shown below.On top of that all my other projects in that folder are also not working and shows lots of errors.

[image: The sample image of current error is:]

Need help.If any one has any idea , please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to Sync Gradle?

Comment: just clean and rebuild your project...and tap on sync project with gradle files

Comment: ya I cleaned the project , rebuild the project but nothing has happened till now.

Comment: try this: **File > invalidate cache and restart**

Comment: Looks like its missing the android sdk files, check it.

Comment: @NezSpencer thanks it helped.